# Copying 100 files at a time using terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, cp

Is there an option to copy first 100 files from a directory to another location using the `cp` command? If not is there any other way to do this? Do i need to write a script?

Comment: directory with sub folders or "flat"

Comment: Flat directory :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cp $(ls | head -n 100) new_path/
```

Comment: I will advise to [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).